# Error "Single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" al leer csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
from pandas import Series
from matplotlib import pyplot
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
series = Series.from_csv('GOOG.csv', header=0)
result = seasonal_decompose(series, model='multiplicative')
result.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

obtengo siempre el mismo error:

> Single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Los datos del fichero csv son del tipo:

```
Date        Close
2013-10-14  435.224274
2013-10-15  438.155212
2013-10-16  446.113464
2013-10-17  441.523315
2013-10-18  502.437134
...
```

Estoy intentando obtener el csv anterior filtrando las dos columnas que me interesan de otro. El csv que utilizado originalmente tiene la estructura:

> Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
>   2012-05-18,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,38.230000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   ...

De las columnas que se índica en la cabecera me interesan únicamente `Date` y `Close`, que son los datos que quiero utilizar para dibujar las gráficas.

¿Cómo lo podría solucionar?

Comment: Carla ¿qué separador tiene tu csv? Si pudieras pegar las primeras líneas del archivo como tal sería de gran ayuda. El error es lanzado por `Series.from_csv` supongo ¿no?

Comment: Hola FjSevilla. Utilizo como separador una coma (,) aunque también he llegado a utilizar (;) por si era ese el problema. El error lo genera el código "result = seasonal_decompose(series, model='acumulative')" y las primeras líneas del csv son "19/8/04;49.845.802" y "20/8/04;53.805.050". Muchas gracias

Comment: Entonces una línea sería `19/8/04;49.845.802`, ¿Solo tenemos dos columnas, fecha y el valor? ¿Los puntos son separadores de miles o hay algún error? Es decir `49.845.802` es "cuarenta y nueve millones ochocientos..." ¿La cabezera es la que indicas arriba`Date;Close`? Es importante todo esto porque tanto el formato de la fecha, el separador y el significado del `.` (separador decimal o separador de miles) son cruciales a la hora de especificar los parámetros de parseo del csv. El error en principio se debe al separador, pero para que te funcione hay que parsear correctamente las columnas.

Comment: Creo que como dices tengo errores al transformar los datos. El csv que utilizado originalmente tiene la cabecera "Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume" con múltiples columnas en las que se indica el valor diario de cada etiqueta "2012-05-18,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,38.230000,38.230000,573576400", por lo que al transformados ha fallado cambiando los separadores. De las columnas que se índica en la cabecera me interesan únicamente Date y Close, que son los datos que quiero utilizar para dibujar las gráficas. ¿cuál sería la mejor forma de hacerlo? Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Carla he creado una respuesta basándome en la estructura del csv original que muestras, si tienes problemas y es posible te recomiendo que subas el csv o parte de el a Dropbox, GoogleDrive, etc y lo compartas para que podamos reproducir el código. Cualquier problema comenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Series.from_csv` está marcado como "Deprecated" en favor de [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) mucho más flexible. Para obtener una serie basta con pasar el parámetro `squeeze` con valor `True` siempre y cuando el csv conste de solo una columna (más indice) o especifiquemos que solo lea estas dos de forma explícita si tiene más.

Para leer solo parte de las columnas del csv (en este caso dos) basta con pasar una lista al argumento `usecols`.

Vamos a partir del siguiente csv (inventado según lo que muestras en los comentarios sobre la estructura de tu csv original):

> Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
>   2012-05-18,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,38.230000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-19,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,39.560000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-20,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,40.120000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-21,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,42.230000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-22,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,45.856000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-23,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,44.230000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-24,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,46.230000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-25,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,48.820000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-26,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,50.590000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-27,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,42.450000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-28,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,55.450000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-29,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,47.120000,38.23000‌​0,573576400
>   2012-05-30,42.049999,45.000000,38.000000,58.690000,38.23000‌​0,573576400

El error que muestras está lanzado desde NumPy y se debe generalmente a un mal parseo del csv que ocasiona que alguna columna falte o sobre, ocasionando un indexado ilegal en el array  de NumPy usado internamente para almacenar los datos. En un csv correcto puede pasar por no especificar el separador correcto usado en él. Para ello basta con usar el argumento `sep`.

Por otro lado, debemos parsear la columna de fechas adecuadamente ya que en caso contrario será leída como cadenas Python (`dtype object`) y `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose` lanzará una excepción ya que espera una serie temporal. Para evitar problemas es recomendable pasarle una lista al argumento `parse_dates` con las columnas que son fechas y queremos que sean parseadas a `datetime`. Si tus fechas son de estilo europeo (con el dia primero, como `19/8/04`) debes indicarlo con ele argumento `dayfirst`.

Con todo ello el código debería ser (recuerda cambiar la ruta del csv según tu caso):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
series = pd.read_csv('datos.csv', squeeze=True, header=0, parse_dates = [0],
                     index_col =[0], sep=',', usecols = ["Date",  "Close"])

result = seasonal_decompose(series, model='multiplicative')
result.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

Lo que nos muestra la siguiente gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código testeado en:

```
Python      3.6.3
Matplotlib  2.1.0
NumPy       1.13.3
Pandas      0.21.0
Statsmodels 0.8.0
```